# How can i get a javascript value from webview to android?

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I'm trying to get a value of 0 or 1 if the class 'logout' is present in my webview. (the base idea was that if i find the 'logout' class it means that the user is loged in and that's what i need to know)

So far i have searched and come to something like this.

the JavscriptInterface() class

```
private static class JavascriptInterface{
    private Map<String,String> valueMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        public String set(String key, String value){
            valueMap.put(key,  value);
            return "";
        }

        public String get(String key){
            return valueMap.get(key);
        }
}
```

in onCreate()

```
webview_mycare = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_mycare);
webview_mycare.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
js = new JavascriptInterface(); 
webview_mycare.addJavascriptInterface(js, "jsinterface");
js.set(JS_KEY, "-1");

    webview_mycare.loadUrl(
                    "javascript:document.function hasClass(element, cls){ return(' '+ element.className +' ').indexOf(' '+ cls +' ')>-1;"
                  + "javascript:document.function var el = document.getElementsByClassName('front-page');"
                  + "javascript:document.function if(hasClass(el,'logout')==true){ "
                  +         "window.jsinterface.set('"+JS_KEY+"','1');"
                  +     "}else{"
                  +         "window.jsinterface.set('"+JS_KEY+"','0');"
                  +     "}"
                );
    try{
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }catch(InterruptedException ex){

        }

    String v=js.get(JS_KEY);
    System.out.println("isMapPage: getValue: value="+v);  
    if("1".equals(v)){  
        Log.e(">>>>>>>>>>>>", "JS_KEY "+ v);
    }else{
        Log.e(">>>>>>>>>>>>", "JS_KEY "+ v);
    }

    webview_mycare.loadUrl(URL);
```

URL is a string with my web address

So far the result is -1.
What im i writing wrong?

Comment: If you are using addJavaScriptInterface don't forget to use the  @JavascriptInterface annotation and limit your app to Android 4.2+, otherwise it may be vulnerable to attackers. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)

Comment: @Robert Ok, i have renamed the 'JavascriptInterface' with 'JScInterface' and putted the @ JavascriptInterface before 'onCreate()', still the answer is -1. I think im missing something in the javascript code.

Comment: you mean Activity#onCreate()? do not sleep on main thread. and also which url is loaded in web view? and, js code in loadUrl() looks like unavailable as url. past js code in your pc browser and check if it works. There are many samples to use js interface.

Comment: Have you considered that the JavaScript code may be execute asynchronously? Then you are asking for the result before the JavaScript code has been actually been executed.

Comment: @Robert Sorry, i'm pretty new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final String URL = "file:///android_asset/index.html";
    private WebView mWebView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); 
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                String user = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text)).getText().toString();
                if (user.isEmpty()) {
                    user = "World";
                }
                String javascript="javascript: document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='Hello "+user+"!';";
                view.loadUrl(javascript);
            }
        });
        refreshWebView();
        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void refreshWebView() {
        mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        refreshWebView();
    }

}
```

and this xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:hint="What is your name?" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="Update Web View"/>

    <WebView 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
       android:id="@+id/webview" />

</LinearLayout>
```